# howto handel a couple of asp.net pages with nearly the same code?

Tags: asp.net

hi i have a problem, i'm working on a aps.net page which have a couple of sites.
the sites are nearly eqal but have e.g. a other count of labels the but the method names are the same.

what would be the best design strategy to keep all this sites easy to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive a base class from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and inherit from this for your specific pages.

```
public class MyApplicationBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // common methods/fields here
}

public partial class SpecificPage_1 : MyApplicationBasePage { }
public partial class SpecificPage_2 : MyApplicationBasePage { }
```

...etc

Have a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebParts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx). Dont repeat the code if its same thing in several views. Just compose it of several elementary partial views.